# While executing the program "error: '(' or '[' expected"

Tags: java, android

```
@Override
public void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position) {
    Fragment objFragment = null;

    switch (position) {
        case 1:
            objFragment = new home_Fragment;
            break;
    }

    //update the main content by replacing fragments
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.container, objFragment)
            .commit();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Change this line:

```
objFragment= new home_Fragment;
```

with

```
objFragment= new home_Fragment();
```

You are calling the constructor **without** ().